# Como trabalhar uma sessão segura no PHP utilizando cookies para que a sessão não expire ao fechar o navegador?

Tags: php, segurança, session, autenticação, cookies

No PHP, costumo trabalhar a autenticação de usuários em área restrita usando a variável `$_SESSION`, porém quero mudar este método para cookies para que a sessão não encerre ao fechar o navegador. Em sites como Google e Facebook, o usuário entra em sessão e se voltar em 30 dias por exemplo, a sessão ainda está ativa.

O código que estou utilizando:

autentica.php

```
session_start();
// Verifica se houve POST e se o usuário ou a senha é(são) vazio(s)
if (!empty($_POST) AND (empty($_POST['usuario']) OR empty($_POST['senha']))) {
    header("Location: login.php"); exit;
}

$usuario = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['senha']);

// Validação do usuário/senha digitados
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE (`usuario` = '". $usuario ."') AND (`senha` = '". $senha ."')  LIMIT 1";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {
    // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
    echo '<script language="JavaScript">
       <!--
          alert("Dados Incorretos!\n\n");
          history.back();
          //-->
       </script>'; 
} else {
    // Salva os dados encontados na variável $resultado
    $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    // Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

    // Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
    $_SESSION['UsuarioID'] = $resultado['id'];
    // Redireciona o visitante

    header("Location: index.php"); exit;
```

Nas páginas restritas eu utilizo o código a seguir:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['UsuarioID'])) {
session_destroy();
header("Location: autentica.php"); exit;
}
```

Ao fechar o navegador a sessão criada no código acima expira. Eu também acredito que esteja muito inseguro.

Comment: O que você quer guardar nos cookies? O uso de Session já implica o uso de um cookie (que guarda o id da sessão).

Comment: Deve haver algum motivo por trás dessa mudança, não é? Escalabilidade? Desempenho? Talvez seja melhor reformular a pergunta para deixar claro o que você quer fazer. Isso deve atrair respostas de qualidade.

Comment: Na verdade eu quero apenas que a sessão dure mais tempo, por exemplo: 30 dias. No caso da variável $_SESSION se eu fecho o navegador a sessão expira. Isso pode ser feito somente com cookie ou eu estou equivocado?

Comment: Não sei como estás a autenticar os utilizadores nem como estás a iniciar a sessão, mas eu uso `$_SESSION` à muitos anos e a sessão só expira se o utilizador fizer _logout_, limpar os _cookies_ da página em questão ou o administrador do servidor limpar os ficheiros das sessões, caso contrário passam-se anos e ela continua activa. Dito isto, seria bom ver o teu código para podermos rever o mesmo e facultar a ajuda que precisas.

Comment: Na verdade Anderson, no caso do facebook é usado muitas coisas além de cookie. No seu caso é interessante utilizar o cookie para armazenar um valor da $_SESSION para evitar que a mesma seja destruída. Existem alguns métodos de se fazer isso com $_SESSION + Cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode substituir as funções de gerenciamento de sessões com código que armazena os dados de sessões em cookies. Aí usa a função [session_set_save_handler](http://www.php.net/session_set_save_handler) para susbtituir as funções.

Aqui tem uma [classe para armazenamento de dados em cookies](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3545-PHP-Session-handler-that-stores-data-in-cookies.html) que faz precisamente isso. A classe usa criptografia para que os dados de sessões não sejam visiveis aos browsers.

Este método tem a vantagem de não apenas permitir que as sessões durem para além do tempo que o browser fica aberto, mas também permite que a sua aplicação com sessões funcione em ambiente distibuido com vários servidores Web em cluster.

No entanto, não é muito recomendando quando pretende armazenar muitos dados em sessões pois, aumenta o tamanho do cookie e isso faz demorar os acessos do browser ao servidor.

Cookies também têm um limite de tamanho de 4KB, pelo que os dados de sessões não podem exceder esse tamanho.

Um método mais simples que pode resolver o seu problema é definir o tempo de duração do cookie de sessão é usar a função [session_set_cookie_params](http://www.php.net/session_set_cookie_params) e usar um valor diferente de 0 para o parâmetro lifetime.

Comment: Eu desconhecia esta solução mlemos. Fiz os testes usando o mesmo código que postei acima e funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado por compartilhar seu conhecimento.

Comment: Opa @anderson ainda bem que resolveu. Não precisa agradecer. Compartilhe o seu conhecimento para retribuir.